# Plugged in, battery not charging, not running down

Tags: power-management, battery

This morning, after being plugged in all night, my Asus N550J, Xubuntu Saucy, showed 28% battery.

When it is plugged in, it shows the Charging icon, yet the percent charge never goes up.

When it is unplugged, the charge goes down -- now it is at 15%.

I tried restarting. I tried another AC adaptor. No difference.

What is the problem here? Is the  battery in fact charging correctly, but the indicator is failing to ever go up when it is charging?

Or is there a real  problem with battery charging? (But if so, why does  the  computer last indefinitely on AC power, and why does the indicator show "Charging"?)

(As a maybe-related issue: 3 days ago the fan got really loud, intermittently. The laptop was not noticeably hotter than usual when this occured. But that loudness stopped.)

EDIT: Answer below.

Comment: Your laptop battery must be in trouble. Try changing your battery.

Comment: yep it probably is a broken charger. "why does the computer last indefinitely on AC power" think about it. regardless of broken software or broken hardware or fuctional both the above remains true. If its true  **always** then it being true *today* is of no special meaning and is not something you can draw a conclusion from or link something else to :-)

Answer (score 3):

Just hold down the button 7 seconds until it shuts down, then *another* 10/20 seconds. The orange battery light may go from blinking to steady orange. That fixes it.

Comment: You mean 10/20 seconds holding the button or waiting? While I'm doing this, the laptop should be plugged or not?